# How Do I Make A Clear Window in Pygame

Tags: python, window, pygame

Is there a way to get a clear window in Pygame?

I know that I can have a borderless window, but is it possible to get rid of everything inside of the window to make it clear? I want to make some stuff that works on top of my desktop, but it needs a shape that isn't rectangle. I do know that it would still be a rectangle, I just don't want it to look like one.

Comment: Lol, I didn't notice that I put in instead of to.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone have an answer? D:

Comment: Only way I could think of is have your program read what is behind it and blit that to your display surface.

Comment: @cmd I thought about doing that, but I have my background change every 15 minutes. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible within regular Pygame. A Google search turned up "Window Manager Extensions", though, which explicitly supports non-rectangular windows.

Comment: Weird... I've seen other programs that can do it.